# RPI 3, Python: How do I play and record a sine wave at the same time?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've previously used the sounddevice package which has a playrec function, but it does not release memory which makes the program freeze after a while. It also creates cracling noises with my new Asus Xonar U7 USB sound card. Is there a different way to create, play and record sine waves?